# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error while importing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to import .js file but facing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error while importing. I just dived into MEAN stack and facing these issues while importing files. Even the angular files are not getting imported .

server.js

```
//Variables------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./app/models/user');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var appRouters = require('./app/routes/api')(router);
var path = require('path');
//---------------------------------------

//Middleware--------------------------
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing 
application/x-www-form-
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname+'/public'))
app.use('/api',appRouters);


 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',function(err){
  if(err){
  console.log('Not connected '+err);
   }else{
  console.log('Connected to db');
   }
   });

//-------Fontend Routes
  app.get('*',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
 });


 app.listen(port,function(){
 console.log('Running the server');
 });
```

index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
   import file
   **<script src="app/app.js"></script>**
   </head>

   <body>
   <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
   </nav>
   </div>

   </body>
  </html>
```

app.js

```
 console.log("testing");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> app.get('*',function(req,res){
>   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
> });
> ```

You said that for `*`, i.e. any URL other than those starting with `/api` or `/static` (which you defined first), to serve up the content of `index.html`.

You then have:

```
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

… which is going to get `index.html` and try to treat it as JavaScript. Which it isn't.

Get the URLs to your scripts correct (or get the server to serve the right data for the URLs you are requesting).

Comment: Thanks for the info.... i changed the path directory which is serving static files from "app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname+'/public'))"........ app.use( express.static(__dirname+'/public')).. and it worked since it the serving directory.